# Create column index on dataframe to_sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe and I want to create a table with an index on a column.
To create the table use

```
my_dataframe.to_sql(
    name="my_table"
    , con=my_engine
    , schema='dbo'
    , index=False
    , if_exists='append'
    , chunksize=15000
)
```

I would like the table to be created similar to the query

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    <all columns>,
    INDEX index_name (index_column_name)
);
```